# How can I adjust how large the width is of the wheel picker? Even when I adjust the frame, the selected value goes outside the frame and interferes

Tags: swift, swiftui, width, picker

Here is my code, when it runs, it gives me the picker, and the value of 10 where you can touch the screen is very wide, I can scroll through the wheel through most of the screen. I want to make it much more thin so you can only scroll through the numbers if you basically touching the numbers.

VStack {
Picker(

```
                selection: .constant(10),
                label: Text("Reps"),
                content: {
                    
                    Text("10").tag(10)
                    Text("9").tag(9)
                    Text("8").tag(8)
                    Text("7").tag(7)
                    Text("6").tag(6)
                    Text("5").tag(5)
                    Text("4").tag(4)
                    Text("3").tag(3)
                    Text("2").tag(2)
                    Text("1").tag(1)
                      
                }

            )
                .pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
        }
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078718/swiftui-how-to-resize-pickerview) your question?